# Return ReasonPhrase and (text) Content from webapi to Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way to return a ReasonPhrase and some plain text from aspnet core to Angular? I create a new record and return it's id to the client, along with a ReasonPhrase for Toastr.

I have this on my webapi controller:

```
    [HttpPut("save")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Save(MyModel model)
    {
        model.Id = await _service.Save(model);

        return Ok(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            ReasonPhrase = $"Record saved",
            Content = new StringContent(model.Id.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"),
        });...
```

And when I try to read it the content in Angular (8) like so:

```
save$.subscribe((result: any) => {
      console.log(result.content);
```

I see this:

```
{headers: Array(1)}
headers: Array(1)
0:
Key: "Content-Type"
Value: ["text/plain; charset=utf-8"]
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

No idea what I'm doing wrong (is it even possible to do this?) but I want the value to be my newly created id but it's ["text/plain; charset=utf-8"] instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to return a ReasonPhrase and some plain text from aspnet core to Angular?

To achieve requirement, you can refer to the following code snippet using an anonymous type with two properties named `ReasonPhrase` and `Content`, like below.

```
[HttpPut("save")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Save(MyModel model)
{
    //...

    return Ok(new
    {
        ReasonPhrase = $"Record saved",
        Content = model.Id.ToString()
    });
}
```

On Angular client

```
.subscribe((result: any) => {
  console.log(result);
  console.log(result.reasonPhrase);
  console.log(result.content);

  // ...
  // code logic here
  // ...
});
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the mega slow response - this worked perfectly, thanks!